# attaching @Entity annotations to jaxb-generated classes from a wsdl

Tags: binding, jaxb, cxf, wsdl2java

My goal is to add `@Entity` annotations to the classes that are generated from a wsdl.  I'm using `cxf-codegen-plugin`'s `wsdl2java` goal, and pointing at a local wsdl file.  I can generate all the sources without any problem, but when I try to add a binding file, I'm running into problems.

Here's a segment of the wsdl (the file is `CAAudit.wsdl` and is in my resources directory):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://www.ocse.gov/quick/wsdl/CAAudit.wsdl" 
    xmlns:audw="http://www.ocse.gov/quick/wsdl/CAAudit.wsdl" 
    xmlns:audx="http://www.ocse.gov/quick/wsdl/CAAudit.xsd" 
    xmlns:qikrsp="urn:us:gov:hhs:acf:qikrsp" 
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
    name="CAAudit"
>
  <wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.ocse.gov/quick/wsdl/CAAudit.xsd" 
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    >
      <xsd:import namespace="urn:us:gov:hhs:acf:qikrsp" 
                  schemaLocation="QuickResponse.xsd" />

      <xsd:complexType name="NotifyCAAuditRequest" >
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element ref="qikrsp:QuickResponse" />
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
....
```

My first question is I'm really not certain what should go in the binding file.  First, I'm pretty sure that I need `jaxws` bindings to work with the wsdl (the `jaxb` binding only has the `schemaLocation` attribute), although I don't need to generate web service classes.

Next, I'm not sure I'm not sure if the introduction of a new xmlns in the schema element will cause problems for an xpath search.  I did have problems running it with notepad++'s xpath evaluation.

Also, I'm not sure if the fact that the QuickResponse element (which is the class I want to annotate) is defined by a reference is hindering my efforts.  I'm not sure if or how (or where) I would include the referenced xsd file.

Here is one possible binding file (I was just trying to get an `@Generated` on the class to start with):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jaxb:bindings
        xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
        xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
        xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net"
        jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="annox"
        jaxb:version="2.1"
        >
    <jaxws:bindings wsdlLocation="CAAudit.wsdl"
            node="/wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types">
        <jaxb:bindings node=".//xsd:schema">
            <annox:annotate>@javax.annotation.Generated({"JAXWS"})</annox:annotate>
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxws:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not manage to customize schema embedded in WSDL. This are my latest efforts:

https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin/blob/master/tests/jaxws/src/main/resources/wsdl-bindings.xjb

What works with WSDLs is attaching customizations via SCD. But SCD does not allow proprietary customization elements (like `annotate:*`). So that won't help with `jaxb2-annotate-plugin`.

So the only thing which would probably work is to extract schema from the WSDL into an own file.